# Setup subdomain in tomcat7

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have both apache2 and tomcat7 installed on my server
apache runs on port `80` and tomcat on port `8080`

My domain `pedjaapps.net` points to my server ip and that works fine(apache handles it as it should)

Now i want my subdomain `api.pedjapps.net` on port '8080' to point to subfolder `api` on tomcat server

i tried editing server.xml and adding something like this:

```
<Host appbase="webapps/api" autodeploy="true" name="api.pedjaapps.net" unpackwars="true" xmlnamespaceaware="false" xmlvalidation="false">
    <Context docbase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/api" path="" reloadable="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

but it still opens default tomcat page

api.pedjaapps.net also points to my servers ip in dns, if that is relavent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the default tomcat page, remove (or rename) webapps/ROOT then change the name of webapps/api to ROOT.  This will make your api web application the default tomcat application. This is a quick (and dirty) solution if it meets your needs.

If this is not sufficient, you can set up virtual hosts in either apache or tomcat. If done in tomcat, you will need to have each virtual host point to a separate webapps area. See this for setup: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Comment: No, it doesn't, cause i will definitely have more subdomains some time in the future

Comment: In that case you will have to set up virtual hosts in either apache or tomcat. If done in tomcat, you will need to have each virtual host point to a separate webapps area. See this for setup: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html